# Sentence variations in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, frameworks, pep8, sentence-synthesis

A few months ago I found something with this kind of syntax:

```
{Hello|Dear} {Customer|client|person},

xxxx
```

This will generate sentences like:

```
Hello Customer,
```

or

```
Dear person,
```

How is it called? Is there a framework which parses this? If not, how would I do this?

I am planning to use this in an automation script which builds sentences.

Any further idea's on which frameworks I should use for building sentences in python? It makes ugly code when long blocks of text are embedded in python scripts.

Comment: In python you can perform 'string formatting'. The randomness/choices are done outside of the formatting though. So you can make list of options and pick one randomly. Other option could be to use Jinja2 or other templating framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want random greetings,

```
import random
greetings = ["hello", "dear"]
print("{} person".format(str(random.choice(greetings))))
```

Comment: Use multiple {} and multiple variables in . format().          s = "{} person good {}". format ("hello", "morning")